# Spring classpath prefix difference

Tags: java, spring, classpath

Documented at [4.7.2.2 The classpath*: prefix](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-classpath-wildcards) it states

> This special prefix specifies that all
> classpath resources that match the
> given name must be obtained
> (internally, this essentially happens
> via a ClassLoader.getResources(...)
> call), and then merged to form the
> final application context definition.

Can someone explain this?

What is the difference between using `classpath*:conf/appContext.xml` as opposed to `classpath:conf/appContext.xml` without the asterisk.

Comment: Future readers, also see this bug, with a "status=declined".  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/16017   Just in case the URL ever eventually fails, the title of the bug post is " Import of an XML file from the root of a JAR file with wildcard classpath and wildcard path does not work [SPR-11390] "

Answer (score 232, accepted):

**SIMPLE DEFINITION**

The `classpath*:conf/appContext.xml` simply means that **all appContext.xml files** under `conf` folders in all your jars on the classpath  will be picked up and joined into one big application context.

In contrast, `classpath:conf/appContext.xml` will load **only one such file**... the first one found on your classpath.

Comment: there is one more interesting difference between them. See my question also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985770/runwith-and-contextconfiguration-weird-behaviour

Comment: One very important thing - if you use the * and Spring finds no matches, it will not complain.  If you don't use the * and there are no matches, the context will not start up (!)

Answer (score 43):

The `classpath*:...` syntax is useful primarily when you want to build an application context from multiple bean definition files, using wildcard syntax.

For example, if you construct your context using `classpath*:appContext.xml`, the classpath will be scanned for every resource called `appContext.xml` in the classpath, and the bean definitions from all of them merged into a single context.

In contrast, `classpath:conf/appContext.xml` will obtain one and only one file called `appContext.xml` from the the classpath. If there is more than one, the others will be ignored.

Comment: Will classpath* look in subdirectories too? In other words, if I have appContext.xml in the classpath root and one in /dir/appContext.xml, will it load both when I use classpath*:appContext.xml?

Answer (score 24):

**classpath*:** It refers to a **list of resources** and **loads all** such files present in the classpath and ***list can be empty*** and if ***no such file is present*** in the classpath then application **does not throw any exception** (just ignores the error).

**classpath:** It refers to a **certain resource** and **loads only the first** file found on the classpath and ***if no such file is present in the classpath*** then **it will throw an exception**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
class path resource [conf/appContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Comment: [Official Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) "It's not possible to use the classpath*: prefix to construct an actual `Resource`, as a resource points to just one resource at a time." plus I just got this weird error, that is how I ended up here. If you are going to import resource then it makes no sense to use wildcard classpath prefix.

Answer (score 1):

The source code of Spring:

```
public Resource[] getResources(String locationPattern) throws IOException {
   Assert.notNull(locationPattern, "Location pattern must not be null");
   //CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX="classpath*:"
   if (locationPattern.startsWith(CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX)) {
      // a class path resource (multiple resources for same name possible)
      if (getPathMatcher().isPattern(locationPattern.substring(CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX.length()))) {
         // a class path resource pattern
         return findPathMatchingResources(locationPattern);
      }
      else {
         // all class path resources with the given name
         return findAllClassPathResources(locationPattern.substring(CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX.length()));
      }
   }
   else {
      // Only look for a pattern after a prefix here
      // (to not get fooled by a pattern symbol in a strange prefix).
      int prefixEnd = locationPattern.indexOf(":") + 1;
      if (getPathMatcher().isPattern(locationPattern.substring(prefixEnd))) {
         // a file pattern
         return findPathMatchingResources(locationPattern);
      }
      else {
         // a single resource with the given name
         return new Resource[] {getResourceLoader().getResource(locationPattern)};
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain?