# RunWith and ContextConfiguration weird behaviour

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I have this very simple class :

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:/application-context-this-does-not-exist.xml"})
  public class HTMLSourceExtractorImplTest {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    public void test(){
         String [] beans = context.getBeanDefinitionNames();
             for(String bean : beans){
                 System.out.println(bean);
             }
         System.out.println("Testing");
    }
}
```

This context file that is specified in classpath DOES NOT EXIST. I can put virtually any name I want and the code does not break. I mean the test runs just fine, as if that file really exists.

If I do a small change, from : **classpath*** to **classpath** , then it beaks, saying that this file does not exist, which is the behavior I would expect in the first case also.

Spring Version 3.2.3.RELEASE.

Can someone explain this weird behavior?

**EDIT**

Things from logs as suggested:

```
     20:47:26,923 INFO  [GenericApplicationContext] Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@3df6c65c: startup date [Fri Jun 07 20:47:26 PDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
```

I even tried to output all beans from application context:

```
  org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor
  org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor
  org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor
  org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor                   
  org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassProcessor.importAwareProcessor
```

Seems to me that in case of a wildcard, Spring will create a default empty Application Context

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Quote from JavaDoc will probably answer your question:

```
/**
 * Pseudo URL prefix for all matching resources from the class path: "classpath*:"
 * This differs from ResourceLoader's classpath URL prefix in that it
 * retrieves all matching resources for a given name (e.g. "/beans.xml"),
 * for example in the root of all deployed JAR files.
 * @see org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader#CLASSPATH_URL_PREFIX
 */
String CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX = "classpath*:";
```

As there are no XML files matching the name `application-context-this-does-not-exist.xml` on your classpath, your configuration is equal to `@ContextConfiguration(locations={})` => **empty application context**.

However when you use `CLASSPATH_URL_PREFIX = "classpath:"`, that equals to saying *"load this non-existing file"* => **error loading context configuration**.

Comment: I honestly do not see any link between the documentation that you provided and the default application context created. It is obvious that one empty context is indeed created, but the documentation does not clearly states it. Thank you for your answer though. Will upvote for the effort, but I wish there was an obvious statement in docs.

Comment: I've described that - with no XMLs to load, all you are left with is just an empty context.

Comment: you did, no doubt about it. But this is obvious from the code I ran. No offense, but to me, the code should break and not pass on. I will accept this later, unless I get a better explanation. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why it should break? Because it does not have any config to load? The `classpath*:` is a wildcard prefix which acts as a search filter, not exact location.

Comment: exactly. A SEARCH FILTER, there was nothing found.. This can generate a lot of debate, at least between me and you :)

Comment: I don't see where you see the problem... there is no issue there. `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` aways creates a basic application context, which is then merged with all configurations loaded based on the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation parameters. Your parameters lead to no configuration being loaded and hence the empty context.