# Load a spring configuration from another module

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-batch

I'm working on a spring application that contains submodules, roughly looking like the following:

```
project
|-- module1
|   |-- src
|   |   `-- main
|   |       |-- java
|   |       `-- resources
|   |           |-- applicationContext.xml
|   |           `-- web.xml
|   `-- pom.xml
|-- module2
|   |-- src
|   |   `-- main
|   |       |-- java
|   |       `-- resources
|   |           `-- batch-jobs.xml
|   `-- pom.xml
`-- pom.xml
```

**module1** contains the web app configuration.
**module2** contains using `spring-batch` to run batch jobs, which are configured in `batch-jobs.xml`.

Inside `applicationContext.xml` I have the following line:

```
<import resource="classpath*: batch-jobs.xml" />
```

As far as I can tell, this file is being loaded. I assume this because previously I was using `classpath: batch-jobs.xml` (without the `*`) and it couldn't find the file.

In spite of loading this file, I get a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. If I copy everything from `batch-jobs.xml` over to `applicationContext.xml`, it works fine.

Comment: Does module1 see module2's class resources at runtime? I.e. is the batch-jobs.xml file in the classpath?

Answer (score 3):

When you use the asterix like this

```
<import resource="classpath*: batch-jobs.xml" />
```

it ignores files it can't find (among other things)

See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985770/runwith-and-contextconfiguration-weird-behaviour) for details

Make sure you refer to its spring configuration xml with leading slash, like this:

```
<import resource="classpath:/batch-jobs.xml" />
```

If it still complains about file batch-jobs.xml not found make sure you have module 2 jar on your classpath (add dependency on module2 to module 1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven copy resource plugin to copy the resource to module1 project( add the copy resource plugin in module1 pom.xml). Say suppose you modify your import statement `<import resource="classpath*: springjobs/batch-jobs.xml" />` You can use copy resource plugin to copy xml files from module2's resource directory to module1.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy--common-resources</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/spingjobs</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/../project/module2/src/main/resources</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but the directory is not clean

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach when you have multiple modules and your base web module is unaware of bundled modules like plugins (Audit, Logging).

```
classpath*:applicationContext-*.xml
```

You have to follow the naming convention for your spring configuration XML files (applicationContext-m1.xml, applicationContext-m2.xml) in order to load the configurations using classpath scanning by spring.

Answer (score 0):

This can also achieved using maven configuration.I don't know , whether you are implementing Maven or not. But you can follow the below statement to achieve that....

```
Module A, 
xml file of A is a.xml
Module B.
xml file of B is b.xml

I have to include the config file of Module B in Module A.

Step 1:
In Module A pom.xml file include the dependency of Module B.
        <dependency>
            <groupId><module_package></groupId>
            <artifactId><module_name></artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

Step 2:
Go to the xml configuration file(eg a.xml) and import the configuration file of Module B.
<import resource="b.xml"/>
```