# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

I am getting below error: when running the below code. I have he xml file(report-context.xml) at src/main/resources folder only. Not sure why is it not working? it is maven project.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int execResult = -1;
        ApplicationContext appCont = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "classpath:/report-context.xml");
        Application appBean = (Application) appCont.getBean("abcLauncher");
        if (appBean != null) {
            appBean.run();
            execResult = appBean.resultCode();
        }
        System.exit(execResult);

    }
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML
document from class path resource [report-context.xml]; 
nested exception is  java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [beans xml file   
name]cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

if i change the line of code to :

```
ApplicationContext appCont = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "classpath*:/report-context.xml");
```

It gives below error though the bean is already configured in xml file?

```
Exception in thread "main"
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No bean named 'abcLauncher' is defined
```

Appreciated any help on this

--adding content part of my xml file

```
<bean id="analystMeterDataServices" class="com.abc.pg.analystmeter.service.AnalystMeterDataServicesImpl">
        <property name="messageSender" ref="messageSender" />
        <property name="analystMeterDao" ref="analystMeterDao" />
        <property name="dataFileName"
            value="${data.dir}${data.smselector.paramsfilename}" />
        <property name="lastRunDateformat" value="${data.lastrundateformat}" /> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="abcLauncher" class="com.abc.pg.analystmeter.AnalystMeterLauncher">
        <property name="appSelectorDataServices" ref="analystMeterDataServices" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Please show the content of your file.

Comment: Ok, now I'm confused. Which code gives you an error and which one is fine? Please simplify that in your question.

Comment: i have given code and error in order in my post. i just updated please refer updated.

Comment: Refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294423/spring-classpath-prefix-difference), then check that file is actually there.

Comment: thanks for the comments: as i mentioned, i tried both the ways, classpath* and without * too. the issue not resolved. not sure why

Comment: The point isn't to try them just like that, but to understand what each is doing. It doesn't seem like the file in `src/main/resources` is on your application's classpath.

Comment: Did you try removing the slash?

Comment: yes, I removed slash as well, still says could not find file location.