# Spring import multiple resources in single line

Tags: spring

I have around 10 xml files to be to imported to main spring config file.
All of them have a common string in their name "asset". So their names are like `Aasset.xml, Basset.xml` and so on ... In my main spring config file, i am importing them as following:

```
<import resource="classpath*:*asset.xml" />
```

But this is not working when we package our code into a jar and try to run it. At runtime bean dependencies are not found.

Any ideas on this? I dont want to import files one by one.

Comment: How do you package a jar? Maven? Double check if the xml files are in the jar (unzip it). Does importing one by one work?

Comment: We use maven and files are present in jar, i have checked that. If i give complete name it works.

Comment: Try classpath: not classpath*: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294423/spring-classpath-prefix-difference  Is it a single jar?

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda: After changing "classpath*" to "classpath" it is not considering "*" in filename  as wildcard entry instead it considers it as part of filename and fails to load it. Yes its a single jar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all the spring application context files in a file system and then load it

```
<import resource="classpath*:file://Disk:spring/context/*asset.xml"/>
```

(Or)

Create a META-INF folder parallel to src then load like the following :

```
<import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/context/*asset.xml"/>
```