# I get some issue when I set up my project with spring+springmvc+mybatis

Tags: spring, mybatis

Dao:

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao {
    int searchAccount(String account);
    int getPurview(User user);
}
```

Service:

```
public interface LoginService {
    int judgeForUser(User user);
    boolean searchAccount(String account);
}
```

ServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class LoginServiceImp implements LoginService {

    @Resource
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public boolean searchAccount(String account) {
        if (userDao.searchAccount(account) == 1){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int judgeForUser(User user) {
        return userDao.getPurview(user);
    }
}
```

mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="dao.UserDao">

    <select id="searchAccount" parameterType="String" resultType="int">
        select 1 from users where account = #{account} limit 1
    </select>

    <select id="getPurview" parameterType="model.User">
        select purview from users where account = #{account} and password = #{password}
    </select>

</mapper>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring-mybatis.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring MVC servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:mvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

mvc-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver"
          p:templateEngine-ref="templateEngine"
          p:characterEncoding="UTF-8"/>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolvers">
            <set>
                <ref bean="templateResolver"/>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/"
          p:templateMode="HTML"/>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter"
          class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
            <list>
                <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"
          p:maxInMemorySize="3000000"/>

</beans>
```

spring-mybatis.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="dao"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="mapping"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="service"/>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:dbconfig.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource" init-method="init" destroy-method="close"
          p:url="${jdbc.url}"
          p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}"
          p:filters="stat"
          p:maxActive="8"
          p:initialSize="1"
          p:maxWait="60000"
          p:minIdle="1"
          p:timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000"
          p:minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
          p:validationQuery="SELECT 'x'"
          p:testWhileIdle="true"
          p:testOnBorrow="false"
          p:testOnReturn="false"/>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:mapping/*.xml"/>
        <property name="plugins">
            <array>
                <bean class="com.github.pagehelper.PageInterceptor">
                    <property name="properties">
                        <value>
                            helperDialect=mysql
                        </value>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer"
          p:basePackage="dao"
          p:sqlSessionFactoryBeanName="sqlSessionFactory"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"/>

</beans>
```

when I run it. it show this error, I do not know why it can't creating the bean?!

error:

> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext
>   Context initialization failed 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'listViewServiceImp': Injection of resource
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'IListViewDao' defined in file
>   [/Users/Mario.Hu/Documents/mybatis/target/mybatis-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/dao/IListViewDao.class]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlSessionFactory' while setting
>   bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [spring-mybatis.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed
>   to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'org.springframework.core.io.Resource[]' for property
>   'mapperLocations'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve resource
>   location pattern [classpath:mapping/*.xml]: class path resource
>   [mapping/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist    at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'IListViewDao' defined in file
>   [/Users/Mario.Hu/Documents/mybatis/target/mybatis-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/dao/IListViewDao.class]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlSessionFactory' while setting
>   bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [spring-mybatis.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed
>   to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'org.springframework.core.io.Resource[]' for property
>   'mapperLocations'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve resource
>   location pattern [classpath:mapping/*.xml]: class path resource
>   [mapping/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [spring-mybatis.xml]: Initialization of bean failed;
>   nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException:
>   Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to
>   required type 'org.springframework.core.io.Resource[]' for property
>   'mapperLocations'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve resource
>   location pattern [classpath:mapping/*.xml]: class path resource
>   [mapping/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'org.springframework.core.io.Resource[]' for property
>   'mapperLocations'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve resource
>   location pattern [classpath:mapping/*.xml]: class path resource
>   [mapping/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist    at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:610)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve
>   resource location pattern [classpath:mapping/*.xml]: class path
>   resource [mapping/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not
>   exist     at
>   org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourceArrayPropertyEditor.setAsText(ResourceArrayPropertyEditor.java:116)
>   27-May-2017 23:35:23.398 严重 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more
>   listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the
>   appropriate container log file 27-May-2017 23:35:23.420 严重 [RMI TCP
>   Connection(2)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context []
>   startup failed due to previous errors

why? I follow other people to build these code! but it can't work for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the error message it seems to be not able to find the resource directory mapping in your classpath.

Alternatively use the below in your spring-mybatis.xml (Notice the extra *)

```
<property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:mapping/*.xml"/>
```

This will not return an exception if not found. Check more for differences in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294423/spring-classpath-prefix-difference)