# Location of spring-context.xml

Tags: java, spring, junit

When I run my application on tomcat the spring-context.xml file is located at

> /WEB-inf/spring-context.xml

This is ok. But running a junit test I have to supply it with the location of my spring-test-context.xml like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/spring-test-context.xml"})
```

The only way this works is if the file is located in

> /src/spring-context.xml

How can I get my application to find my spring-context files in the same location? So that it works with junit testes and deployed on tomcat?

I tried this and it gave me alot of errors about not finding any beans, but it didn't say it couldn't find the file..

```
classpath:/WEB-INF/spring-test-context.xml
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As duffymo hinted at, the Spring TestContext Framework (TCF) assumes that string locations are in the classpath by default. For details, see the JavaDoc for [ContextConfiguration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html).

Note, however, that you can also specify resources in the file system with either an absolute or relative path using Spring's resource abstraction (i.e., by using the "file:" prefix). You can find details on that in the JavaDoc for the [modifyLocations()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/support/AbstractContextLoader.html#modifyLocations%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String...%29) method in Spring's `AbstractContextLoader`.

So for example, if your XML configuration file is located in `"src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml"` in your project folder, you could specify the location as a relative file system path as follows:

```
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml")
```

As an alternative, you could store your Spring configuration files in the classpath (e.g., `src/main/resources`) and then reference them via the classpath in your Spring MVC configuration -- for example:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/spring-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

With this approach, your test configuration would simply look like this (note the leading slash that denotes that the resource is in the root of the classpath):

```
@ContextConfiguration("/spring-config.xml")
```

You might also find the [Context configuration with XML resources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#testcontext-ctx-management-xml) section of the reference manual useful.

Regards,

Sam

*(author of the Spring TestContext Framework)*

Comment: Excellent. Got it working with `file:WebContent/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml` (not using maven) . Thanks for the help!

Comment: One should mention that Spring somehow knows where "src/" is located. In my mvn3 / surefire / Spring setup this works also (and prevents resource file doubles), but I suspect that Surefire prepares the context for Spring in a way that "src/" is a valid start (and "main/" wouldn't be). Thus you should know, where your "relative" path must start for getting this to work.

Comment: `@ContextConfiguration` has supported a `classes` attribute for JavaConfig since Spring 3.1: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html#classes--

Comment: See "Context configuration with annotated classes" in the reference manual for details: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-javaconfig

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that /WEB-INF is not in the CLASSPATH for a web app.  However, /WEB-INF/classes is.

Your problem with testing is that you aren't running in an app server, so WEB-INF/classes isn't part of the CLASSPATH by default.  I'd recommend setting up your tests so that either WEB-INF/classes is in the test CLASSPATH or use a relative or absolute file path to find them.