# Spring and testing with TestContextFramework

Tags: spring, testing, junit

I wanted to write few unit tests for my application that uses Spring MVC. I read the manual page at the Spring home page:`http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html` and it seems that this Spring testing framework could be really useful.

But here are the questions:

1.If I understand it right, to use any of the annotations for testing like `@ContextConfiguration` I need to use `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`? But is it possible to use two runners (probably not), I just wondered if one can use Spring runner and mockito one, because I am using mockito to mock normal objects.

2.I have a question about loading xml context files with `@ContextConfiguration`. I have my .xml files in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring`, how can I load them using `ContextConfiguration`? I tried

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations="/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml")
@ContextConfiguration(locations="webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml")
@ContextConfiguration(locations="/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml")
@ContextConfiguration(locations="WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml")
@ContextConfiguration(locations="/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml")
@ContextConfiguration(locations="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml")
```

but I always get `class path resource [some_path] cannot be opened because it does not exist`.I am wondering then what path should I use?

EDIT:
  the second problem was that WEB-INF is not in the classpath, here is the topic that helped me [Location of spring-context.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385452/location-of-spring-context-xml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, you cannot have two `@RunWith`, instead you should use other ways that Mockito provides to create a Mock stand-in.
2. The way to specify multiple locations is this:

   ```
   @ContextConfiguration(locations={"first.xml", "second.xml"})
   ```