# How to import spring configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have this project structure:

[image]

What I can to write in `@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "what I must write here?" })`
for success import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/spring_config.xml")
```

See [Location of spring-context.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385452/location-of-spring-context-xml)

You can also move files to the *resources* folder:

> you could store your Spring configuration files in the classpath (e.g., src/main/resources) and then reference them via the classpath.

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/WEB-INF/spring/spring_config.xml")
```

Comment: Ignore my previous comment - this is fine. Got @ContextConfiguration mixed up with something else, forgot it's only used in test context.

Comment: classes ? Are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you will need to add `webapp` as a source folder, so that `WEB-INF` is available at the top of the classpath (as it will be in the deployed app). Then you can use `/WEB-INF/spring/security_config.xml`.

Alternatively, some people prefer to put their XML files in `src/main/resources` instead.