# Inject @PersistenceContext in test unit for spring

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, junit4, spring-test

I have problem when injecting entityManager in my test class. I think that this is because i can't load my spring context in my test class.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'noteDeFraisDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
```

this is my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {NoteDeFraisTestConfig.class})
@Transactional

@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class NoteDeFraisDAOIT
{
    @Autowired
    private NoteDeFraisDAO noteDeFraisDAO;

    @Test
    public void myTest()
    {

    }

}
```

And this is the configuration for the test I know that when I use new there will be no inject of entitiesManager define in the dao but I don't know what should I do.

```
@Configuration
public class NoteDeFraisTestConfig {

    @Bean
    NoteDeFraisDAO noteDeFraisDAO()
    {
        return new NoteDeFraisDAO();
    }
}
```

I have tried to set my ContextConfiguration to my applicationContext but it didn't work I think that it is because the directory WEB-INF doesn't belong to the classpath. How can I fix this??

This is the structure of my project
[image]

thanks.

**Update**

this is my final test class

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"file:web/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml", "file:web/WEB-INF/db-config.xml","file:web/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml","file:web/WEB-INF/security-config.xml"})
@Transactional
public class NoteDeFraisDAOIT
{
    @Autowired
    private NoteDeFraisDAO noteDeFraisDAO;

    @Test
    public void myTest()
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, the problem is that the `ApplicationContext` loaded for your test does not contain the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. Assuming that's declared properly in `applicationContext.xml`, the linked solution below will help.

> I have tried to set my ContextConfiguration to my applicationContext but it didn't work I think that it is because the directory WEB-INF doesn't belong to the classpath. How can I fix this??

That's covered here: [Location of spring-context.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385452/location-of-spring-context-xml/10522417#10522417)