# How to get Spring ContextConfiguration to load applicationContext.xml from src/main

Tags: eclipse, spring-test

I have a small Spring webapp.  I have some plain unit tests, but I'm now trying to write a test that simply validates the expected wiring of my beans.

I've gotten my test to basically work by simply copying my regular "applicationContext.xml" file into src/test/resources and giving it a different name, and then giving that name to the @ContextConfiguration annotation.  I've verified this running the test class in Eclipse.

However, I really don't want to copy the default applicationContext.xml just so I can use it in the test.  I really just want to use the default one, so I don't have to maintain a copy of it.

I'm using Gradle, and I imagine I could configure something in the build script so that test runs would add "src/main/webapps/..." to the classpath, but that likely won't help when executing the test from Eclipse.  I don't want to manually configure the run configuration, either.

What I've said should be enough to go on, but this is what I currently have above my test class declaration:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(value = {"/testApplicationContext.xml", "/testResources.xml"})
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered this *duplicate* question several years ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10522417/388980