# Access file present in /test/resources - classpath issue

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm working on a Spring multi-module project. One of the child modules has some files under /test/resources/certs/ and a property file under /test/resources/test-ssl.properties.

`───resources
   │   test-ssl.properties
   ├───certs
   │       test-keystore.p12`

`test-ssl.properties` has a property that points to `/certs/test-keystore.p12`file.

`server.ssl.trust-store=/certs/test-keystore.p12`

In child modules pom.xml I'm using Maven plugin test-jar and in parent pom I've added this module as a dependency.

With this structure integration test present in parent module is able to successfully read `classpath:test-ssl.properties` but it fails to resolve its property value.

Spring throws `FileNotFoundException: \certs\test-keystore.p12`. What change we can do to make Spring read a file present in test jar?

Also tried the following patterns,

`server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:/certs/test-keystore.p12`

`server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:certs/test-keystore.p12`

`server.ssl.trust-store=classpath*:/certs/test-keystore.p12`

Please note that this test property doesn't try to load any certificate. It is there because property placeholder can find some value for the property during build.

Comment: I hope the files are under `src/test/resources`? The classpath entry should look like `classpath:/test-ssl.properties` ...

Comment: Tried this but no go. Spring is able to read `test-ssl.properties` file successfully but the value of `server.ssl.trust-store` property.

Comment: I'm not sure if spring itself can read a certificate file cause a certificate must be done during the start of the JVM...

Comment: This test property doesn't load any certificate, it is there so that property placeholder can find some property during integration test. This can be any file of any extension.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved by changing `integration-test` phase to `process-test-resources`.

Credit goes to the following answer of [Pascal Thivent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2607409/2801909):

> The content of the test output directory (target/test-classes) is on the class path, not src/test/resources. But resources under src/test/resources are copied to the test output directory by the [resources:testResources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/testResources-mojo.html) goal (which is bound by default to the process-test-resources phase).